# Finding common words in multiple text files and saving them to new text file

Tags: matlab

If i had 10-20 text files and each file contains at-least 4-5 words which are common in all, how to get those words and to save them to a new text file. 
I have tried many things, as my text files are coming one by one, so I cannot count the number of text files. Is there any way to save the text separately into different cell arrays without using a loop and then find common words.
Here is the code--

```
sdirectory = 'C:\Users\anurag\Desktop\Animals\Annotations\';
textfiles = dir([sdirectory '*.eng']);
sdirectory1 = 'C:\Users\anurag\Desktop\Animals\Images\';
imgfiles = dir([sdirectory1 '*.jpg']);

num_of_files = length(textfiles);
C = cell(num_of_files,1);

for w = 1:length(textfiles)
  file = [sdirectory textfiles(w).name];
  STR = importdata(file);
  BL = cellfun(@lower,STR,'uni',0);
  B = regexprep(BL,'<.*?>','');
  B(strcmp(B, '')) = [];
  tmp = regexp(B, '/| ', 'split');
  C{w} = [tmp{:}];
end

where = [];

for j = 1:length(C)
  file1 = [sdirectory1  imgfiles(j).name];
  file2 = [sdirectory textfiles(j).name]; 

  if find(strcmp(C{j},'alligator'))
    where = [where num2str(j) '.eng, '];
    disp(file2);
  end
end
```

The `file2` variable will show the path of matching text file to text `alligator`. But it will not store the path, but will overwrite the path as the new loop begins. So how to store each path separately so to access store data in text files separately  and find common words in them.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Comment: So you want to read a text file, create a list of words from it and then write this word list to a new file?

Comment: As per my question, i want the common words among the text files found after match, and then these words are to be written to new text file.

Comment: There are atleast two text files to find the common words, not just one file.

Comment: I would have used 'strsplit' to concatenate the content of each file into separate cell arrays; throw these into a larger cell arrays and then act on this larger cell with a loop that contains: c{i}=find(strcmp(c{i},c{i-1})) where each c{i} is the cell corresponding to each file and i runs from 2 to #files. by the end of this process c{#files} would be the desired cell array.

Comment: can you show an implementation.

Comment: @oligilo can you please tell how to store content into separate cell arrays.

Comment: My biggest problem is with varable `file2`. `file2` stores one address at a time, and so as new loop occurs it deletes old path and stores new path and so on until all files having word `alligator` are found. I want the address not to be overwritten and must be saved to a cell array.

Comment: you need to separate your reading phase and your assessing phase. I'd suggest reading the text files with a cimbination of {fopen,fgetl,feof,strsplit,cat} one at a time. after you imported each file into a different cell array you could put these cells into a yet larger cell that lets you index them and use the find and strcmp constructs efficiently.

Comment: the command 'unique' might also improve the efficiency of the comparison phase (after importing the files into cells).

Answer (score 0):

You should first read in the files you are working with and store the words as cell arrays containing strings. Then you should compare the cell arrays in pairs and compare the results in pairs and son on until you have a single cell array.

If you have four files and (A, B, C, D) are four cell arrays of words from the files, you should compare A and B (result is AB), C and D (result is CD), then you should compare AB and CD to get the final cell array of words that are in all four files.

An example

```
basedir = '';
files = dir([basedir '*.eng']);
filenames = strcat({basedir}, {files.name});
```

Now `filenames` will hold the path to all the files you want to work on. You should then write a function that given a path opens the file and creates a cell array of words in the file, lets call this function `read_my_data`.

```
wordlists = {};
for i = 1:numel(filenames)
  wordlists{i} = read_my_data(filenames{i});
end
```

If you have two cell arrays of strings `A` and `B` then you can find duplicates by sorting them both and then iterate over the arrays.

```
function C = duplicates(A,B)
  i = 1; j = 1; k = 1;
  C = {};
  A = sort(A);
  B = sort(B);
  while i <= numel(A) & j <= numel(B) 
    switch strcmp(A{i}, B{i})
      case -1
        i = i + 1;
      case 0
        C{k} = A{i};
        i = i + 1;
        j = j + 1;
        k = k + 1;
      case 1
        j = j + 1;
    end
  end
```

You can then loop over `wordlists` and find duplicates

```
while numel(wordlists) > 1
  j = 1
  tmp = {};
  for i = 1:2:numel(wordlists)-1
    tmp{j} = duplicates(wordlists{i}, wordslists{i+1});
    j = j + 1;
  end
  wordlists = tmp;
end
```

Note that you need to make sure that `numel(wordlists)` is even or 1.

Comment: but for this i have both strings from different files but, i am stuck over `file2` variable which overwrites the path each time new path come. How to solve that problem.

Comment: Sir, I can do as you told but how to store the path in file2 variable separately so that it can not be overwritten again, as it would help in finding how many paths have come. Then i can access them and can find common words among the files.